# Does this algorithm take up too much extra space to be "in place"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

The assignment is to sort negative and positive numbers from a vector. The catch is that the algorithm must be O(n) and in place.
My "solution" is:

```
def Rearrange(arr):
    neg = []
    pos = []
    for x in arr:
        if x < 0:
            neg.append(x)
        else:
            pos.append(x)
    return neg + pos
```

So, what I'm wondering is if this algorithm is in place or not? I know that the loop and append operations satisfy an in place algorithm. But what about the list that stores the values? Does it use too much extra space to satisfy an in place algorithm? If it does, is there an easy fix to this problem that's apparent? Right now I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: You essentially duplicate the array, so I won't say it's in place.

Comment: To be in-place it has to use less than O(n) extra space and modify the original array.  Try to think of a way you can do it by only swapping elements

Comment: I don't see how you can do this in place *and* O(n). Either you calculate 2 lists and append (in which case you can't do in place, as you can't be in 2 places at the same time), or you make one list and then work out where to put elements each time, which I think will be >O(n).

Comment: Also, you `return neg + pos`, i.e. a new array, so it can't be in-place for this reason alone. Are you confusing in-place with O(1) space complexity? Your algo seems would be O(1) space if you would `pop` form the original array, but _not_ in-place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to sort the whole array, or just have negative values on the left and positive values (and 0) on the right?

If what you want to achieve is this second thing, then the following function should work (it works in place and it is O(n)):

```
def rearrange(array):

    left = 0
    right = len(array) - 1

    while left < right:
        if array[left] >= 0 > array[right]:
            array[right], array[left] = array[left], array[right]
            left += 1
            right -= 1
        elif array[left] < 0:
            left += 1
        else:
            right -= 1

>>> array = [-5, 6, 7, -4, 2, 0, -1]
>>> rearrange(array)
>>> array 
[-5, -1, -4, 7, 2, 0, 6]
```

Comment: Nice, but it seems not to be stable, i.e. in OP's version, the result would be `[-5,-4,-1,6,7,2,0]`

Comment: Basically, this is a single-step (no recursion) in-place `quicksort` with pivot element 0. Or rather, just the `partition` part.

Answer (score 0):

No. This solution is not in place. Two new objects (lists) are created, which you continually appended to according to the logic you have specified.

As far as I am aware, you cannot get an in-place *view* of your data using only the standard library.

If an in place solution is important to you, you can use a 3rd party library such as `numpy`.

If an O(n) solution is important, you should use a generator or `list.append` in a `for` loop to 2 lists.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by a view?  If I understand the problem (end up with a vector aka python list where all the negative #'s are on the left, positive on the right, and any 0's in between), this should be doable in O(n) steps using 6 variables (2 to keep track of a negative value and its starting location, 2 for same for positive, and 2 to keep track of where you've looked from left and right)

Comment: @Foon, see link in update on how this can be done better than O(n).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the variable `inplace` but you can achieve `O(n)` with this:

```
def rearrange(arr):
    result = []
    for i in arr:
        if i < 0:
            result.insert(0, i)
        else:
            result.append(i)
    return result
```

**EDIT**

Following the @Chris_Rands proposal this solution using `deque` seems to be the fastest:

```
from collections import deque

def rearrange2(arr):
    result = deque()
    for i in arr:
        if i < 0:
            result.appendleft(i)
        else:
            result.append(i)
    return result
```

Roughly `28%` faster than the accepted solution according to `%timeit` results.

```
%timeit rearrange_accepted(nums)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.2 ms per loop

%timeit rearrange2(nums)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.84 ms per loop
```

Comment: But `list.insert` is O(n) by itself to the front of a list, a deque would work better I guess

Comment: This is O(n) but not in place. Though it's not clear what OP wants. How can you be in place to return 2 lists? You can't be in 2 places at the same time!!

Comment: @jpp Vote to close?

Comment: @jpp in the OP's code they return a single list (via concatenation). Also `list.insert` is O(n) for each call (it's not like appending, which is O(1) https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @jpp yes, but it *could* be, unlike returning 2 new lists

Comment: @Chris_Rands, I'd argue it would then no longer be O(n) since it's not an O(1) task to figure out where to put an entry. *But* I'm  happy to be proven wrong. The accepted answer doesn't seem to work.